# Is it picture noise or did I captured the stars of our galaxy?

Tags: filters, astrophotography, sky, night-photography, nature

I captured this image of empty sky using my phone in the direction of orion constellation and applied some filters using an app. Can anyone explain what is this? [image]

Comment: It looks like just sensor noise.

Comment: _applied some filters using an app_... **What** filters?

Comment: That is way milky photo of darkness and not a photo of the milky way :)-  I do not see any stars at all.  **Did you use a tripod?  Do you have an app that allows you to make long exposures or change the ISO ? You need to provide very detailed info about how you took the photo.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a severely underexposed image with heavy noise reduction applied. Minor differences between "almost black" and "totally black" have caused the patterns you see.

Comment: Those undefined "filters" most likely amplified the visible noise patterns too.